# Tensorflow: How to concat different dim embeddings in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to concat different dim embeddings in tensorflow :

So I want to concat three embeddings :

- First_embedding   =  300 dim
- Second_embedding  =  50  dim
- Third_embedding   =  6   dim

Now I want final vector as 356 dim shape :

```
concat( [ 300 dim , 50 dim , 6 dim ] ) ---> 356 dim
```

I can do that easily in numpy with np.column_stack:

```
first_embedding = np.random.randint(10,20,[10,300])
second_embedding = np.random.randint(10,20,[10,50])
third_embedding  = np.random.randint(10,20,[10,6])

concat = np.column_stack((first_embedding,second_embedding,third_embedding))

print(concat.shape)
```

output:

```
(10, 356)
```

I am not able to do same thing in tensorflow, So If I am creating three embedding in tensorflow :

```
import  tensorflow  as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                           shape=[None,None]
                          )

sentences_sec = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                           shape=[None,None]
                          )

sentences_third = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                           shape=[None,None]
                          )

Word_embedding = tf.get_variable(name="Word_embedding", 
                                 shape=[24,300], 
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.array(load_embedding_matrix_1)), 
                                 trainable=False
                                )


first_embedding_loopup= tf.nn.embedding_lookup(Word_embedding,sentences)



Word_embedding_second = tf.get_variable(name="Word_embedding_2", 
                                 shape=[24,50], 
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.array(load_embedding_matrix_2)), 
                                 trainable=False
                                )


second_embedding_loopup= tf.nn.embedding_lookup(Word_embedding_second,sentences_sec)



word_sentences_third = tf.get_variable(name="Word_embedding_3", 
                                 shape=[24,6], 
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.array(load_embedding_matrix_3)), 
                                 trainable=False
                                )


third_embedding_loopup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(Word_embedding_third,sentences_third)
```

I am trying to use tf.concat but for that all dim should be same ,

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone kindly give me some advice on How can I concat diff dim and get same shape as I am getting from np.column_stack ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the **axis** to properly concatenate your word vectors. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

a = tf.get_variable(name='a', initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), shape=(512, 24, 300))
b = tf.get_variable(name='b', initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), shape=(512, 24, 50))
c = tf.get_variable(name='c', initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), shape=(512, 24, 6))

print(tf.concat(values=[a, b, c], axis=-1).numpy().shape)
>>> (512, 24, 356)
```

Comment: SO I am assuming it is [batch_size , sentence_lenght , emb_dim ] . so is it possible if sentence_length is different ? like [ 512, 21, 300 ] , [512, 22, 50 ] and [512, 20, 6] ?

Comment: Set a constant sentence lenght and define a masking layer is the solution in such case.